# (discord.py) How to display bot typing indicator in DMs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I heard that `ctx.typing()` exists but I want my bot to display the indicator in DMs. Here is my code so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # i want the bot to display 'typing...' for 1 second
    if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        with open('dmresponses.txt') as input_file:
            long_list = [line.strip() for line in input_file]
        await message.author.send(random.choice(long_list))
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `typing()` context manager:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        async with message.channel.typing():
            with open("dmresponses.txt") as input_file: # do stuff inside
                long_list = [line.strip() for lin in input_file]
        await message.author.send(random.choice(long_list)) # what to do after typing
```

And if you want to emphasize the typing duration, you can include a delay by using `asyncio.sleep()`:

```py
import asyncio # required for the sleeping

async with message.channel.typing():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    # some stuff
await message.channel.send("Done!")
```

---

**References:**

- [Context managers in Python](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)
- [`Messageable.typing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.typing) - Messageable is somewhere that you can send a message (Text channel, DM, group chat etc.). `message.channel` is a `discord.TextChannel` object
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)
- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)